# Why and how hibernate_sequence is using for id generatior

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jhipster

I'm faced out an issue with ID generation for my entities generated by JHipster:

1. Dev environment on H2 database
2. Prod environment on Postgres
3. I have one entity "station" with two fields "id" and "name"
4. Creating a liquibase script which imports dictionary in "station" table like 
   `INSERT INTO station (name) VALUES ('Adygeya')` without ID definition
5. Trying to add station on dev environment - OK
6. Trying to add station on prod - Hibernate tries to add new station with duplicated ID

WHY?

My research was shown that only for postgres and oracle in initial scheme jhipster created a new sequince "hibernate_sequence" which is used for new entities creation.

So I'm fixed out this wrong behaivour by adding specific sequence name for my entity ID generation rule

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "station_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "station_gen", sequenceName = "station_id_seq")
private Long id;
```

Now I have just 3 questions:

1. Why JHipster using one sequince for all tables for postgres and oracle?
2. Where is it configured?
3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of JHipster? I think this is default strategy either in spring-data or Hibernate. Using only one sequence for all tables does not explain duplicate keys issue. I have same setup and did not encouter it.

Comment: Yes that's the default Hibernate strategy.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou JHipster v. 3.9.1

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The reality of the problem in item 4. I'm adding new objects in table with own sequence through SQL directly. For example 3 times. In local sequince it will be 4 - nextval, for hibernate_sequence it will be 1. Once I will create new object with hibernate it will be duplication.

Comment: @JulienDubois Could you please suggest how to change this behaivour?

Comment: OK, I understand why I did not get the problem: I don't use INSERT directly from SQL in Liquibase, I use `<loadData>`in XML to insert record from CSV data. The XML migrations use Hibernate under the hood which is why it probably works. It could be a regression bug.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Yes, I've tried to use `<loadData>` too. It is working the same way. I've researched how Liquibase doing this work and found that it just generating SQL commands and executes it directly on database without Hibernate at all. You can beleve me because the Liquibase starts his work before hibernate will be initialized.

Comment: Could it be related to this issue? https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4690

Comment: @GaëlMarziou This is not exactly my issue (my issue is vice versa) but the resolution will fix my problem too! And this solution helps me to understand the recommended way to configure entity right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will post here my answer wich was found with help of @GaëlMarziou and @Julien Dubois.

Thats because of history and default behaivour of Hibernate hilo algorithm with GenerationType.AUTO. MySQL doesn't support sequencies so JHipster needs to use this stupid algorithm

JHipster team has found right solution wich will fix my problem. The solution is to use GenerationType.SEQUENCE for all DB but use GenerationType.IDENTITY for MySql. All the details in this commit https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/4516b4ff4d49a96a75fd963b0c7667f198bd9b79

This way I will configure my entities now too.